# No Data shown on Bokeh Graph Jupyter after called random x and y

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I wrote this code on Jupyter, but after calculating the result from random `x` and `y`, Bokeh Graph showed no data?

How can I modify the `x` and `y` so I can show the x and y to Bokeh Graph?

```html
import random
import math
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import notebook_div
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
random.seed(10)
output_notebook(hide_banner=True)

n_step = 1000
n_parts = 10

sigma = 1.  
mu = 0.  

x = np.zeros((n_step, n_parts))
y = np.zeros((n_step, n_parts))


for i in range(n_step - 1):
    x[i + 1, :] = x[i, :] + np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (1, n_parts))
    y[i + 1, :] = y[i, :] + np.random.normal(mu, sigma, (1, n_parts))
    
    
output_notebook()

x  = [x]
y = [y]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))


p = figure(title='Sample',plot_width=800, plot_height=800)
p.line(x='x' ,y='y' ,source = source)


show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong structure for your data. Your data is lists in a list in an array. It should be just a list for the line glyph you are trying to plot. It looks like you want to plot multiple lines so I recommend looking into [multi_lines](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#multiple-lines). You have to put your data in a list of lists for that.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually, the problem is on the data type